# Efficiently Iterating Through Specific Tags in Parsing XML Using xml.etree

Tags: python, xml-parsing, xml.etree, iterparse

I am in the process of parsing a very large XML file that is about 9 GB in size. I have tried the `.iterparse` method, which is, from what I have gathered, the recommended way to go about this task.
However, this seems to take too long. Now, I am trying to implement a multiprocessing approach where I try to parse the elements of interest in separate processes.

I believe it was possible to do `.iterparse('path_to_file.xml, events=("start", "end"), tag='some_tag)` in the past, but it does not look like this is supported anymore.

So, the way I have come up with is this,

```
root = ET.parse('path_to_file.xml').getroot()

for element in root.iter('some_tag'):
   # do something
```

Is there a better way to go about this? From what I know, this is a memory intensive operation.

If there is no other way to do this, is there a way to clear the memory when using this approach? In the same way that we do `element.clear()` when using `.iterparse`?

Comment: If the file is that large, you will have problems already at `ET.parse()`. Note that `iterparse()` in lxml has a `tag` parameter: https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.iterparse-class.html. There are many existing questions about parsing large XML files:  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+xml+large+file+is%3Aquestion.

Comment: I do not believe that the `tag` parameter is supported anymore, https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html
Yes, I have gone through the majority of them. Most of them suggest the use of `iterparse`, however, when I tried it, it took way too long. I am talking hours.

Comment: As I said, the `tag` parameter is supported in lxml.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad. Let me check.